# File upload using selenium Web driver?

Tags: selenium, file, upload

```
WebElement product_image = driver.findElement(By.id("pdt_upload_preview"));
System.out.println("-------Product image selected----------\n-----------------------");
product_image.click();  
product_image.sendKeys("C:\\TEST\\TEST\\Images\\Images(1).jpg");
```

I can't upload the file by using this.

Comment: Hello, seems you are new here. Please introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope no need to click, simply try

```
WebElement product_image = driver.findElement(By.id("pdt_upload_preview"));
product_image.sendKeys("C:\\TEST\\TEST\\Images\\Images(1).jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code isn't working, it's possible that your image upload element is hidden. You could try executing Javascript to reveal the element:

```
WebElement product_image = driver.findElement(By.id("pdt_upload_preview"));

// execute javascript to reveal the element
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", product_image);

// send keys to the element
product_image.sendKeys("C:\\TEST\\TEST\\Images\\Images(1).jpg");
```